# Access attributes/methods comments programmatically in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments

Is there a way for programmatically accessing a method comments? or an attribute comments?

I would like to use it as a description for the method in a documentation which I don't want to be static or generated with rdoc or equivalent.

Here is an example of a Ruby class:

```
Class MyClass
  ##
  # This method tries over and over until it is tired
  def go_go_go(thing_to_try, tries = 10) # :args: thing_to_try
    puts thing_to_try
    go_go_go thing_to_try, tries - 1
  end
end
```

Basically, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
get_comment MyClass.gogogo # => This method tries over and over until it is tired
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

*The whole point* of comments is that they are *not* part of the program! If you want a string that is part of your program, just use a string instead.

In most Ruby implementations, comments already get thrown away in the lexer, which means they don't even reach the *parser*, let alone the *interpreter* or compiler. At the time the code gets run, the comments are long gone … In fact, in implementations like Rubinius or YARV which use a compiler, there is simply no way to store the comments in the compiled executable, so even if they weren't thrown away by the lexer or the parser, there would *still* be no way to communicate them to the runtime.

So, pretty much your only chance is to parse the Ruby sourcefile to extract the comments. However, like I mentioned above, you cannot just take *any* parser, because most of the exisiting parsers throw comments away. (Which, again, is the *whole point* of comments, so there's nothing wrong with the parser throwing them away.) There are, however, Ruby parsers which preserve comments, most notably the ones used in tools such as RDoc or YARD.

YARD is especially interesting, because it also contains a query engine, which lets you search for and filter out documentation based on some powerful predicates like class name, method name, YARD tags, API version, type signature and so on.

However, if you *do* end up using RDoc or YARD for parsing, then why not use them in the first place?

Or, like I suggested above, if you want strings, just use strings:

```
module MethodAddedHook
  private

  def method_added(meth)
    (@__doc__ ||= {})[meth] = @__last_doc__ if @__last_doc__
    @__last_doc__ = nil
    super
  end
end

class Module
  private

  prepend MethodAddedHook

  def doc(meth=nil, str)
    return @__doc__[meth] = str if meth
    @__last_doc__ = str
  end

  def defdoc(meth, doc, &block)
    @__doc__[meth] = doc
    define_method(meth, &block)
  end
end
```

This gives us a method `Module#doc` which we can use to document either an already existing method by calling it with the name of the method and a docstring, or you can use it to document the very next method you define. It does this by storing the docstring in a temporary instance variable and then defining a `method_added` hook that looks at that instance variable and stores its content in the documentation hash.

There is also the `Module#defdoc` method which defines and documents the method in one go.

```
module Kernel
  private

  def get_doc(klass, meth)
    klass.instance_variable_get(:@__doc__)[meth]
  end
end
```

This is your `Kernel#get_doc` method which gets the documentation back out (or `nil` if the method is undocumented).

```
class MyClass
  doc 'This method tries over and over until it is tired'
  def go_go_go(thing_to_try, tries = 10)
    puts thing_to_try
    go_go_go thing_to_try, tries - 1
  end

  def some_other_meth; end # Oops, I forgot to document it!

  # No problem:
  doc :some_other_meth, 'Does some other things'

  defdoc(:yet_another_method, 'This method also does something') do |a, b, c|
    p a, b, c
  end
end
```

Here you see the three different ways of documenting a method.

Oh, and it works:

```
require 'test/unit'
class TestDocstrings < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_myclass_gogogo_has_a_docstring
    doc = 'This method tries over and over until it is tired'
    assert_equal doc, get_doc(MyClass, :go_go_go)
  end
  def test_that_myclass_some_other_meth_has_a_docstring
    doc = 'Does some other things'
    assert_equal doc, get_doc(MyClass, :some_other_meth)
  end
  def test_that_myclass_yet_another_method_has_a_docstring
    doc = 'This method also does something'
    assert_equal doc, get_doc(MyClass, :yet_another_method)
  end
  def test_that_undocumented_methods_return_nil
    assert_nil get_doc(MyClass, :does_not_exist)
  end
end
```

Note: this is pretty hacky. For example, there is no locking, so if two threads define methods for the same class at the same time, the documentation might get screwed up. (I.e.: the docstring might be attributed to the wrong method or get lost.)

I believe that `rake` does essentially the same thing with its `desc` method, and that codebase is *much* better tested than this, so if you intend to use it in production, I'd steal Jim's code instead of mine.

Comment: That was hell of a well written answer I must admit. Thank you for your insights on this. You've made my mind: I'll never do something as hacky as this for my app.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile, there is a "standard" gem `method_source` that solves some of those issues:

https://github.com/banister/method_source

```
Set.instance_method(:merge).comment

Set.instance_method(:merge).source
```

It also comes with recent Rails ([railties >= 5.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9afd9d232c6b533578c7b86df245aa75939091e5#diff-b3e294e4fb1f1e978225734a14db22af)) versions and is used by Pry under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments are (usually) thrown away by the lexer and are not available in the symbol tables to Ruby at execution time**.

I think the closest that you could do is to either

(a) Implement get_comment in such a way that it creates a regex on the fly and searches the source file for a match. You'd need to change your syntax like this ...

```
 get_comment :MyClass, :go_go_go
```

You would convert the symbols to strings, assume that the source file is myclass.rb and search therein for a match on the comment-def-method_name pattern.

(b) Have a method called from every source file which built a global comment table.

Regardless, it's messy and more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: Makes sense. I assume I'm going to change my mind and reconsider my needs. Thanks