# Custom Hook/Callback/Macro Methods

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How do I create a Custom Hook Method in a Subclass?

No need to duplicate Rails, of course -- the simpler, the better.

My goal is to convert:

```
class SubClass

  def do_this_method
    first_validate_something
  end
  def do_that_method
    first_validate_something
  end

  private

  def first_validate_something; end
end
```

To:

```
class ActiveClass; end

class SubClass < ActiveClass
  before_operations :first_validate_something, :do_this_method, :do_that_method

  def do_this_method; end
  def do_that_method; end

  private

  def first_validate_something; end
end
```

Example in Module: https://github.com/PragTob/after_do/blob/master/lib/after_do.rb

Rails #before_action: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_action

Comment: Do you want `first_validate_something` to be called before *any* method is called (even, say, `to_s`)? If not, how is it supposed to decide which methods to "hook"?

Comment: first_validate is called only before the methods listed as arguments, so in this case #do_this_method, and #do_that method

This is what the method definition would look like, to steal from SteveTurczyn: before_operations(before_method, *methods)

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does. My apologies, I'm on mobile and didn't scroll right far enough to see the second and third arguments!

Comment: These are some obvious libraries that pull this off:
RSpec(#before): https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/5598c131bbaf3197881780e2b779f447da71eea4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb

Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L366


But I'm struggling to understand them at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `prepend`. When you call `before_operations` for the first time it creates a new (empty) module and prepends it to your class. This means that when you call method `foo` on your class, it will look first for that method in the module.

The `before_operations` method then defines simple methods in this module that first invoke your 'before' method, and then use `super` to invoke the real implementation in your class.

```ruby
class ActiveClass
  def self.before_operations(before_method,*methods)
    prepend( @active_wrapper=Module.new ) unless @active_wrapper
    methods.each do |method_name|
      @active_wrapper.send(:define_method,method_name) do |*args,&block|
        send before_method
        super(*args,&block)
      end
    end
  end
end

class SubClass < ActiveClass
  before_operations :first_validate_something, :do_this_method, :do_that_method

  def do_this_method(*args,&block)
    p doing:'this', with:args, and:block
  end
  def do_that_method; end

  private

  def first_validate_something
    p :validating
  end
end

SubClass.new.do_this_method(3,4){ |x| p x }
#=> :validating
#=> {:doing=>"this", :with=>[3, 4], :and=>#<Proc:0x007fdb1301fa18@/tmp.rb:31>}
```

---

If you want to make the idea by @SteveTurczyn work you must:

1. receive the args params in the block of `define_method`, not as arguments to it.
2. call `before_operations` AFTER your methods have been defined if you want to be able to alias them.

```ruby
class ActiveClass
  def self.before_operations(before_method, *methods)
    methods.each do |meth|
      raise "No method `#{meth}` defined in #{self}" unless method_defined?(meth)
      orig_method = "_original_#{meth}"
      alias_method orig_method, meth
      define_method(meth) do |*args,&block|
        send before_method
        send orig_method, *args, &block
      end
    end
  end
end

class SubClass < ActiveClass
  def do_this_method(*args,&block)
    p doing:'this', with:args, and:block
  end
  def do_that_method; end

  before_operations :first_validate_something, :do_this_method, :do_that_method

  private    
    def first_validate_something
      p :validating
    end
end

SubClass.new.do_this_method(3,4){ |x| p x }
#=> :validating
#=> {:doing=>"this", :with=>[3, 4], :and=>#<Proc:0x007fdb1301fa18@/tmp.rb:31>}
```

Comment: any thoughts on how to move before_operations above the methods listed?

Comment: Have `before_operations` maintain a list of methods, override `method_added` to check whether the method currently being defined is in that list. That's how Rake's `desc` method works, for example. You can see an example in these two answers of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2948977/2988 http://stackoverflow.com/a/3161693/2988 (Note to self: update to use `Module#prepend`!)

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a new, prepend-based solution to the problem. This allows `before_operations` to be invoked before you have defined the methods, and also does not use any aliasing nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

You can alias the original method to a different name (so `:do_this_something` becomes `:original_do_this_something`) and then define a new `:do_this_something` method that calls `:first_validate_something` and then the original version of the method  Something like this...

```
class ActiveClass
  def self.before_operations(before_method, *methods)
    methods.each do |method| 
      alias_method "original_#{method.to_s}".to_sym, method
      define_method(method, *args, &block) do
        send before_method
        send "original_#{method.to_s}", *args, &block
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like its definitely on the right track, but when I add it to simplified sample code, I get an error, first this: "both block arg and actual block given"

then I delete  &block from the define method line and get this error "undefined method `do_this_method' for class `Context::SubClass'"

any thoughts, on what went wrong?

Comment: I've added a portion to my answer that is inspired by this idea, but fixes it to actually work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of writing the code that does not make use of aliases. It includes a class method `validate` that specifies the validator method and the methods that are to call the validator method. This method `validate` can be invoked multiple times to change the validator and validatees dynamically.

```
class ActiveClass
end
```

Place all the methods other than the validators in a subclass of `ActiveClass` named (say) `MidClass`.

```
class MidClass < ActiveClass
  def do_this_method(v,a,b)
    puts "this: v=#{v}, a=#{a}, b=#{b}"
  end

  def do_that_method(v,a,b)
    puts "that: v=#{v}, a=#{a}, b=#{b}"
  end

  def yet_another_method(v,a,b)
    puts "yet_another: v=#{v}, a=#{a}, b=#{b}"
  end
end

MidClass.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:do_this_method, :do_that_method, :yet_another_method]
```

Place the validators, together with a class method `validate`, in a subclass of `MidClass` named (say) `SubClass`.

```
class SubClass < MidClass
  def self.validate(validator, *validatees)
    superclass.instance_methods(false).each do |m|
      if validatees.include?(m)
        define_method(m) do |v, *args|
          send(validator, v)
          super(v, *args)
        end
      else
        define_method(m) do |v, *args|
          super(v, *args)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def validator1(v)
    puts "valid1, v=#{v}"
  end

  def validator2(v)
    puts "valid2, v=#{v}"
  end
end

SubClass.methods(false)
  #=> [:validate]
SubClass.private_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:validator1, :validator2]
```

The class method `validate` passes symbols for the validation method to use and the methods to be validated. Let's try it.

```
sc = SubClass.new

SubClass.validate(:validator1, :do_this_method, :do_that_method)

sc.do_this_method(1,2,3)
  # valid1, v=1
  # this: v=1, a=2, b=3
sc.do_that_method(1,2,3)
  # valid1, v=1
  # that: v=1, a=2, b=3
sc.yet_another_method(1,2,3)
  # yet_another: v=1, a=2, b=3
```

Now change the validation.

```
SubClass.validate(:validator2, :do_that_method, :yet_another_method)

sc.do_this_method(1,2,3)
  # this: v=1, a=2, b=3
sc.do_that_method(1,2,3)
  # valid2, v=1
  # that: v=1, a=2, b=3
sc.yet_another_method(1,2,3)
  # valid2, v=1
  # yet_another: v=1, a=2, b=3
```

When `super` is called without arguments from a normal method, all arguments and a block, if there is one, are passed to super. If the method was created with `define_method`, however, no arguments (and no block) are passed to super. In the latter case the arguments must be explicit.

I wanted to pass a block or proc on to `super` if there is one, but have been using the wrong secret sauce. I would welcome advice for doing that.

Comment: that's cool, but does require that you define the validees in the super class?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, If the validees were in `SubClass` I don't see a way of modifying them without using aliases. By having them in `MidClass`, but calling them on an instance of `SubClass`, the instance method with the same name in `SubClass` need only contain a line calling a validator and `super`, which is easy to create with `define_method`.

Comment: I see where your coming from, and it does seem the easiest way to meet the requirements.